# create lists with different index in python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a list using a loop, but I want the group to have the same index. Using append, it merges them together. What am I doing wrong?

```
L=[]
l=[]

def information():
    i=0
    while i <= 3:
        if i==0:
            first_name = str(input('First Name : '))
            l.append(first_name)
            i += 1
        elif i==1:
            last_name = str(input('Second Name : '))
            l.append(last_name)
            i += 2
        elif i > 2:
            wish = str(input('If you wish to continue Press Y/y or Press N/n:'))
            if wish == 'y' or wish == 'Y':
                L.append(l)
                start()
            elif wish != 'y' or wish != 'Y':
                break

def start():
    information()        

start()
print('l', l)
print('L ', L)
```

My desired output is:

```
[['sachin', 'tendulkar'],['sachin', 'tendulkar'],['sachin', 'tendulkar']]
```

and I am getting this instead:

```
['sachin', 'tendulkar','sachin', 'tendulkar']
```

Comment: You only have two list instances; set `l = []` **inside the loop**.

Answer (score 1):

A little different than what you had going but this might work

```
Names = []

def information():
    wish = str(input("Do you wish to add a name?  Press Y/y for yes or Press N/n for no: "))
    while ((wish == 'y') or (wish == 'Y')):
        fname = str(input('First Name: '))
        lname = str(input('Last Name: '))
        Names.append([fname, lname])
        wish = str(input("Do you wish to add a name?  Press Y/y for yes or Press N/n for no: "))


information()

print (Names)
```